# how to start string from specific character and remove unwanted characters

Tags: php

I have URL of file which looks like this

```
movieImages/1`updateCategory.PNG
```

it should look like this

```
updateCategory.PNG
```

Comment: Can you describe it more what you want to remove?

Comment: i wanted to remove movieImages/1' from my string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like this, simple

```html
$string = 'movieImages/1`updateCategory.PNG';
$ser = 'movieImages/1`';
$trimmed = str_replace($ser, '', $string);
echo $trimmed;
```

output will be updateCategory.PNG

Comment: What if someday it is named `movieImages/2\`test.PNG`

Comment: What if someday it is named movieImages/1' test.PNG

Comment: what if the special character have been changed?

Comment: Yep those are valid questions but  questions only OP can answer :)

Comment: what do u mean by OP?

Comment: The person who asked this question

Answer (score 1):

Find the position of unwanted character and then pick up the substring after that position.

```
$str="movieImages/1`updateCategory.PNG";
$unwanted="`";
echo substr($str,strpos($str,$unwanted)+1);
```

**Output**

```
updateCategory.PNG
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/503620)**

That is if the string can vary in structure and size. If the first part will always remain same you can simply remove the unwanted stuff using  `str_replace`.

```
echo str_replace('movieImages/1`','',$str);
```